# How can I cd to an alias directory in the Mac OSX terminal

Tags: macos, bash

Is there a way to get into an alias directory from shell with the command "cd" ? It always returns that "htdocs" isn't a directory.

Edit: I made the shortcut with the OS GUI -> rightclicked the htdocs directory and chose "Alias..." (i'm using a german OS if it's not alias maybe it's called shortcut in english?) then i moved it to my home directory (because my terminal starts from there when i open it).

All i want is to open my terminal and type "cd htdocs" so that i can work from there.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

you can make **symbolic link** to it.

```
ln -s EXISTING_PATH LINK_NAME
```

## e.g.

```
ln -s ~/Documents/books ~/Desktop/
```

## Reference

[Enter into a directory through an alias in Mac OS X terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920967/enter-into-a-directory-through-an-alias-in-mac-os-x-terminal)

Comment: I like this approach better. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't want to repost your solution after finding it myself. It's much more useful and linux-y!

Comment: It works but I feel like it defeats the purpose of an alias. What then is the advantage of using an alias vs a symbolic link? @jaepage

Comment: So what do have to call afterwards?

Comment: Note subtle distinction between `ln -s ~/Documents/books ~/Desktop` (which would try to create a symlink called ~/Destop and fail) vs `ln -s ~/Documents/books ~/Desktop/` with trailing slash, creating a symlink _under_ ~/Desktop/ — a shorthand for `ln -s ~/Documents/books ~/Desktop/books`.

Answer (score 15):

> All i want is to open my terminal and type `cd htdocs` so that i can work from there.

The easier approach is probably to ignore the links and add the parent directory of your `htdocs` directory to the `CDPATH` environment variable. `bash(1)` will check the contents of the `CDPATH` environment variable when you type `cd foo` to find the `foo` directory in one of the directories listed. This will work no matter what your current working directory is, and it'll be easier than setting symbolic links.

If the path to your `htdocs` is located `/srv/www/htdocs/`, then you could use `CDPATH=/srv/www`. Then, `cd foo` would first look for `/srv/www/foo/` and change to it if it exists; if not, then it would look for `foo` in the current working directory and change to it if it exists. (This might get confusing if you have multiple `htdocs` directories on your system; in that case, `CDPATH=.:/srv/www` would let you change into a child directory easily but still use the `/srv/www/htdocs/` version if no `./htdocs` directory is present.)

You can add the `CDPATH=/srv/www` line to your `~/.bashrc` file so it works every time you start a terminal.

Comment: This answer is better than mine as it allows for full path auto completion ie. cd htdocs/another/directory.  My answer would require that you know which sub directory you want (no auto complete).

Comment: An FYI: an OS X `alias` file is not a symbolic link, although it functions like a combination of hard link and symbolic link.  It is something supported primarily by the OS X Finder and its origins are way back in the early days of Classic Mac OS.  It's not trivial to use `alias` files in shell programming.  OS X also supports standard symbolic links and hard links.

Comment: @Ned, excellent, thanks; I've removed my completely wrong paragraph. I hadn't expected Apple to use a mechanism above the filesystem layer...

Comment: @Gibron, but there is some nice simplicity in a variable, something I completely overlooked. :)

Comment: Very elegant solution, the only downside to this is when you cd from anywhere you get completion on that path you added. Personally I use cd with first letters and wait for autocomplete to finish for me so I've found the solution a bit annoying.

Answer (score 13):

I personally use this to quickly work in the directory which is present deep inside one of my Volumes in my Mac.

Open your `~/.bash_profile`, create an alias to the directory by adding this:

```
alias cdh="cd /Volumes/Haiku/haiku/src/apps/superprefs"
```

Save it, restart your terminal. Now on typing `cdh` in your terminal should change the working directory to the one mentioned as the alias.

Comment: may need to `source ~/.bash_profile` or `. ~/.bash_profile`. Need to do that in the ubuntu and now need to test it on the actual OSX.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure how OSX exposes Alias links but since you are using bash you can just create a variable in your `.bashrc` file.

On its own line put:

```
htdocs=YourDirectoryPath/
```

Once you have restarted bash you can just type `cd $htdocs`

Comment: I found this to be the least confusing method. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a old hint on macworld to do this in a way that is integrated with BASH: [Enable 'cd' into directory aliases from the Terminal](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050828054129701)

Plus, here is [an answer that uses this solution on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/254005/139766).

Comment: The link you provided looks like it may do the trick, but it's a lot of work.  How about an explanation?

Comment: @ScottBiggs look at the second link for a shorter explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use osascript to do this -- this command seems to work:

> cd "`osascript -e "on run aFile" -e "set aFile to POSIX file aFile as alias" -e "tell application "\""Finder"\"" to return POSIX path of ( ( original item of aFile ) as text ) " -e "end run" path_to_my_Finder_alias 2>/dev/null`"

Basically this command is running an AppleScript that finds the destination path of the argument (path_to_my_Finder_alias) in a subshell, then wraps it in double quotes, and changes the directory to it.

Maybe someone with a little more bash expertise can turn it into a bash alias or function.

Answer (score 2):

### try:

```
alias cdgo=`echo cd /root/go/`
```

cdgo will run, then get command "cd /root/go/" and enter, and it will change your directory in current terminal process

It works on my centos, no test with osx