# Enter into a directory through an alias in Mac OS X terminal

Tags: unix, terminal, alias

Is there a way to do this easily? I have a directory pretty deep in the file system that I access a lot, so I made an alias in my home directory, but it won't let me cd into it. What solutions are there? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can make symbolic links to it just like in unix

e.g.

```
ln -s ~/Library/Documentation .
```

creates a symbolic link to the Documentation folder hidden in your ~/Library folder.

Comment: I actually already did solution 2, that's what seems not to be working. I'll try solution 1 though. Thanks!

Comment: You're right.  It used to be that the command line (or Terminal) was better about resolving Mac-native aliases. Apple must have purposefully taken out that compatibility.  I'm editing my answer to take away "choice # 2", leaving the correct answer.

Comment: Note that this causes `pwd` to report the symbolic link's location, and not the linked-to directory's location.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

Create: `ln -s [Directory] [alias name of the directory]`      // this is saved into current directory;

Delete: `unlink [alias name of this directory]`