# How to cd to an alias directory in OSX terminal

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I created an alias directory, called it "web", and put it in my Documents folder. I couldn't cd to it, so I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781500/how-can-i-cd-to-an-alias-directory-in-the-mac-osx-terminal), and executed this command:

```
ln -s web webs
```

Note that webs was not a pre-established directory or file, the command created it. However, when I do an ls -l, it shows up as "webs -> web".

Regardless, I cannot cd to either web or webs. I think I executed the command incorrectly, and the man file didn't help for clarification. I am relatively new to UNIX, so **I have no idea what I am doing.** Can someone tell me what specific command to execute? Specifically, what's SOURCE and TARGET?

Comment: Just run `mkdir web` and it should all work.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did "mkdir web", and it returned that the file exists. Same with "mkdir webs". When I try to cd to either of them, both still claim to not be a directory.

Comment: @CaptainForge Have you got a *file* in your *current directory* called `web` or `webs`? What's the result of `file web webs`? And BTW, what do you mean by ‘*alias directory*’?

Comment: @Biffen  A "file", no, I don't think so. The alias is called `web`, and `webs` was created from my command in my original post. If those count as files, then yes.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is what ls -l returns:
[/n]
-rw-r--r--@  1 username  wheel           0 Aug 17 09:44 web
[/n]
lrwxr-xr-x   1 username  staff           3 Aug 17 09:17 webs -> web

Comment: `web` is a file and no directory.

Comment: @CaptainForge Please run `file web webs` and show us the output.

Comment: @Biffen both files show `empty`

Comment: @CaptainForge `web` is a *file*, not a directory. As previously pointed out. (Not sure how making a symlink to it would help.)

Comment: Mac OS, prior to OS X, had a concept similar to symlinks called an alias (it's essentially a file that acts a pointer to another file). OS X retains them; they appear in the file system as a file, but command-line tools would need to be programmed to know how to deal with them. In short, no shell I'm aware of knows to check if an alias points to a directory/folder, allowing it to be used as the argument to `cd`.

Answer (score 2):

Symbolic links (aka symlinks, created by `ln -s`) are similar to Mac OS X aliases; both are files that point to other files. However, a program needs to know about them in order to follow them to the intended target. Symlinks are defined by POSIX, and a POSIX-compliant operating system will know how to deal with them. (Mac OS X, for instance, appears to recognize them as aliases.) An alias, however, is just a regular file that the Finder (and other OS-X-aware programs) can interpret as a pointer to another file. As far as `bash` is concerned, it's just a file, and not something you can use as an argument to `cd`.

My suggestion: don't use Mac OS X aliases at all; it appears that OS X can always recognize a symlink as equivalent to an alias, but it is not true that other programs will recognize an alias as a symlink. Remove your alias `web` and replace it with a symlink.

```
rm web
ln -s <whatever web pointed to> web
```